# Android- ListView items with dynamic content

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am having one problem with ListView.
I am generating a list view with dynamic TextViews(white boxes in image) in each item.
The ListView is populated using ArrayAdapter of 'Model' class. Some items can have 2 white boxes, some can have more which depends upon the data/count from 'Model'. Also, I am using ViewHolder pattern and can maintain other states of the list item. But these boxes are added dynamically in getView() method.

So my question is, how to maintain state of these dynamically added TextViews using ViewHolder or any other method when ListView is scrolled.

[image]

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Share some code so anyone can help you..!!

Comment: Btw, I solved the problem. My model is storing some wrong information of number of boxes in row. I corrected it and prob is solved

Answer (score 0):

I guess the no.of boxes changes on scroll, but you need the dynamic no.of boxes to be alloted in a list items?

Solution:

1. Set the size (i.e) no.of boxes in a list item to an integer array. (like: size[position] = 5).
2. The size should be set, before the list adapter or base adapter loads the list items.
3. Now at the end of getView() of base adapter, right the code given below

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i< size[position]; i++){
   //generate textview i.e white boxes here

   }
   ```

I had the same problem in dynamic list, this solved the issue.

If still you have problem kindly post your the code here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a list or some data structure in which to store the content of the data you put in from the ui, for instance a `SparseArray<ModelUI>`. Your ModelUI class should have some string properties to store the text from your dynamic textboxes.

Also, you need to take into account that you're handling two indexes here: one index/key in the SparseArray which is the real index in your list of Model objects and an index of the items visible in your Listview.

Let's say you have a list of 100 items, in your listview you'll always display 10; you'll always have to refer to the firstVisibleIndex from your listView.

If I understand correctly, you'd like to edit a textbox, scroll 50 items, scroll back to the edited item and see the correct text in the textbox, right?